Apache WSGI doesn't import venv packages
I am setting up an Apache server for an older Django app. I want to use my virtualenv configured for Python 2.7. Python 3.10 is installed outside of the virtual environment.
I set my httpd.conf WSGIDaemonProcess to use the venv via python-home and I try including the venv packages via python-path,
WSGIPythonHome /Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project/2.7venv
WSGIDaemonProcess releasejango python-home=/Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project/2.7venv python-path:/Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project:/Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project/2.7venv/lib/python2.7/site-packagesWSGIProcessGroup releasejango
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

Alias /releasejango/static/ /Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project/releasejango/static/

<Directory /Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project/releasejango/static/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /releasejango/ /Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project/releasejango/django.wsgi process-group=releasejango

<Directory /Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project/releasejango/>
    <Files django.wsgi>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

When I visit http://127.0.0.1/releasejango/, I get this error (although I can import django from an interpreter within my venv):
[Fri May 10 16:38:25.937023 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15264] AH00163: Apache/2.4.59 (Unix) mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 10 16:38:25.937210 2024] [core:notice] [pid 15264] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/local/sbin/httpd'
[Fri May 10 15:21:55.989484 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 13122] [remote 127.0.0.1:51789] mod_wsgi (pid=13122): Failed to exec Python script file '/Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project/releasejango/django.wsgi'.
[Fri May 10 15:21:55.990216 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 13122] [remote 127.0.0.1:51789] mod_wsgi (pid=13122): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project/releasejango/django.wsgi'.
[Fri May 10 15:21:56.000137 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 13122] [remote 127.0.0.1:51789] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 10 15:21:56.000825 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 13122] [remote 127.0.0.1:51789]   File "/Users/cakey/Development/releasejango_project/releasejango/django.wsgi", line 13, in <module>
[Fri May 10 15:21:56.000844 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 13122] [remote 127.0.0.1:51789]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Fri May 10 15:21:56.000872 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 13122] [remote 127.0.0.1:51789] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

This import error for django happens whether I have python-path or not.
How can I get Apache to use my venv's Python 2.7 AND the venv's packages? I know it is using python2.7 as it isn't throwing a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'.
